# Can I listen to Qur'an when going to sleep?

Tags: quran, adab

Is it permissible to listen to Qur'an recitation from headphones (using mp3 player, or cell phone etc.) when we are laying on the bed trying to sleep or is it disrespectful to Qur'an?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would say it is okay as long as you pay attention and listen to it.

> وَإِذَا قُرِئَ ٱلۡقُرۡءَانُ فَٱسۡتَمِعُواْ لَهُ ۥ وَأَنصِتُواْ
> لَعَلَّكُمۡ تُرۡحَمُونَ (٢٠٤)
>
> When the Qur'an is read, listen to it with attention, and hold your
> peace: that ye may receive Mercy. (7:204)
>
> Surah Al Araaf, Ayah: 204

Listening to the Qur'an when going to sleep actually puts peace in ones heart, Allah says:

> ٱلَّذِينَ ءَامَنُواْ وَتَطۡمَٮِٕنُّ قُلُوبُهُم بِذِكۡرِ ٱللَّهِ‌ۗ
> أَلَا بِذِڪۡرِ ٱللَّهِ تَطۡمَٮِٕنُّ ٱلۡقُلُوبُ (٢٨)
>
> Those who believe, and whose hearts find satisfaction in the
> remembrance of Allah, for without doubt in the remembrance of Allah do
> hearts find satisfaction. (13:28)
>
> Sura Ar-Ra'ad. Ayah: 28

I will conclude, that it is okay and not disrespectful to listen to the Qur'an while going to sleep as long as you listen to it attentively.

I recall that there is a Hanafi ruling that you must pay attention if the Qur'an is recited (as the above Ayah says), because if you fall asleep you won't be paying attention any more.  If you feel that you are going to fall asleep than I would say to turn it off.

Also, Note that, It is disrespectful to Quran to turn if off in the middle of an Ayat. So, Turn if off, after the ayat is finished

Comment: Sorry to repeat the same answer nearly :), but I haven't seen your answer when I answered.. :(

Comment: @MYamanT it is totally understandable, I have done the same thing many times before :)

Comment: Should the posture not be considered? Is the posture of lying down not disrespectful compared to sitting respectfully?

Answer (score 6):

There is nothing wrong with a Muslim listening to the Quran before going to sleep.

Indeed it is narrated in the saheeh Sunnah that the Remembrance of bedtime reading and listening verses (ayat) of the quran.

And listen to the Quran before sleeping and after
Leading to comfort of the hearts...

> الَّذِينَ آمَنُوا وَتَطْمَئِنُّ قُلُوبُهُم بِذِكْرِ اللَّـهِ ۗ أَلَا
>   بِذِكْرِ اللَّـهِ تَطْمَئِنُّ الْقُلُوبُ
>
> Those who believe and find peace in their hearts from the
>   contemplation of God: Surely there is peace of heart in the
>   contemplation of God!"  [Ar-Ra'd 13:28]

The matter listening to Quran when  be read directed to listener sapiens ...

> وَإِذَا قُرِئَ الْقُرْآنُ فَاسْتَمِعُوا لَهُ وَأَنصِتُوا لَعَلَّكُمْ
>   تُرْحَمُونَ
>
> When the Qur'an is recited listen to it in silence. You may perhaps be
>   blessed. [Al-A'raf 7:204]

But it should be noted, not allow to listen to the Quran in the cases of fun or the departure thinking about it, either when going to sleep there is nothing wrong in that ..

Comment: Should the posture not be considered? Is the posture of lying down not disrespectful compared to sitting respectfully?

Comment: Yes, you are right, Should the posture not be considered when reading Quran.
But here the question and answer to listen to Quran, not reading it

Comment: The posture should probably be discussed. Your answer only talks about listening to the Quran _before_ going to sleep. Rather, the question asks whether the listening of the Quran **while laying down** on the bed is permissible or not.

Comment: The question was listening to the Quran while laying down on the bed to sleep (from title !!)
In general should respect the Quran when you heard (including the laying down)and not entertainment or busy with something when you hear

Answer (score 2):

According to Jafari Fiqh yes it is permissible.

Also the verse:

> وَإِذَا قُرِئَ ٱلۡقُرۡءَانُ فَٱسۡتَمِعُواْ لَهُ ۥ وَأَنصِتُواْ لَعَلَّكُمۡ تُرۡحَمُونَ
>
> When the Qur'an is read, listen to it with attention, and hold your peace: that ye may receive Mercy. (7:204)
>
> Surah Al Araaf Ayah 204

is for when you directly hear reciting Quran from one who recite it and this verse does not apply to indirect hearing like mp3 player.

Comment: Do you mean, He does not have to pay attention when listening from mp3 players?

Comment: @AnwarShah no. I mean obeying this (being silent and hearing) verse is not needed about mp3 player. although it is good to pay attention.

Comment: Should the posture not be considered? Is the posture of lying down not disrespectful compared to sitting respectfully?

Comment: @TabrezAhmed  yes the posture of lying down not disrespectful compared to sitting respectfully but still it is not Haram. more respect is better. but we should not make religion difficult. it is for who seek more nearness to God and is not a Must for all Muslims.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is halal to listen to Quran while sleep.. 
if you fall asleep you still listen to it unconsciously
but the energy from the words of Allah still 
recieve you.. once you get cuncious again 
Then you can turn it off and go back to sleep
Allah knows best !