# Is it okay to leave Quranic Arabic audio playing in the background?

Tags: quran

Is their anything wrong with leaving Quranic audio playing in the background while you get on with your day to day tasks?

I think I read somewhere that if the Quran is being recited, you must listen to it attentively.  So if you have it playing in the background which you do your daily chores, you won't be listening to it attentively.

So, is it a sin to leave it playing in the background like that and not listen to it attentively?

Comment: related: http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/1524/44

Comment: Somewhat relevant [Can I pray tahiyyat al-Masjid during the Qur'an recitation before Friday azan?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/49996/can-i-pray-tahiyyat-al-masjid-during-the-quran-recitation-before-friday-azan/50030#50030)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Listen Quran by radio or recorded, good work will be rewarded rights, no blame on him if he carries on business, or preoccupation, as long as heard as much as possible, and is either a job does not allow him to listen to the Quran, it should not because it goes against literature and respect.

Nawawi said in his book "Clarification of the Literature campaign of the Koran", Page 92:

> ومما يعتنى به ويتأكد الأمر به احترام القرآن من أمور قد يتساهل فيها
>   بعض الغافلين القارئين مجتمعين . فمن ذلك : اجتناب الضحك واللغط والحديث
>   في خلال القراءة إلا كلاما يضطر إليه
>
> And which should be paid attention to make sure it respected the Quran
>   from things that may leniency where some unsuspecting readers
>   combined. For example: avoid laughing and talking through reading
>   Quran  only talk are forced him,
>
> But complied with the words of God:
>
> وَإِذَا قُرِئَ الْقُرْآنُ فَاسْتَمِعُوا لَهُ وَأَنصِتُوا لَعَلَّكُمْ
>   تُرْحَمُونَ
>
> When the Qur'an is recited listen to it in silence. You may perhaps be
>   blessed.
>   [7:204]

**Note:**
[this reference](http://islamport.com/d/2/fqh/1/29/318.html) in book "Fiqh on the four doctrines" "الفقه على المذاهب الأربعة" , Under paragraph: Terms of prostration of recitation "شروط سجدة التلاوة"

shows Shafi'i stated that it is not obligatory prostration (Sajdah) of recitation to who heard the Quran from not "Mokalaf" (human) Such as a machine recorder or radio, So the previous ayah ([7:204]) does not apply in the case of listening to the Quran from the recorder ...

This indicates there is no of sin on who was busy when heard Quran from recorder.

Answer (score 2):

Allah said:

> Then do they not reflect upon the Qur'an, or are there locks upon
>   [their] hearts?
>
> [47:24](http://quran.com/47/24)

It safe to say that if one is chores, one won't be able to ponder over the meanings.  What one should do is set a certain time of day for reading the Quran, morning after or before Fajr is a good time for it is when you wake up and your brain and body has rested.

Source: [Tafseer Ibn Katheer](http://qurancomplex.com/Quran/tafseer/Tafseer.asp?l=arb&t=katheer&nSora=47&nAya=24#47_24)

Answer (score 2):

You may leave Qur'an playing in the background, even if you are not listening attentively.

Quoting the Ayah 204 of Surat Al-'A`rāf:

> [image: Surat Al-'A`rāf, Ayah 204]
>   So when the Qur'an is recited, then listen to it and pay attention that you may receive mercy.

However, the majority of scholars agree that this is only a requirement during prayer. So in your situation they would describe it as:

> Listening to Qur'an while paying attention is better than listening without paying attention, and listening without paying attention is better than not listening at all.

Additionally, they had different views over whether you may talk while listening to Qur'an. Some said you should turn it off, while others said you may talk but in a relatively lower voice.

However, a minority of scholars consider it inappropriate, impolite or disrespectful.

Relevant fatwas (in Arabic): [1](http://www.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&lang=&Option=FatwaId&Id=14575), [2](http://www.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&lang=&Option=FatwaId&Id=11269), [3](http://www.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&lang=&Option=FatwaId&Id=11191), [4](http://www.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=40027), [5](http://www.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&lang=&Option=FatwaId&Id=30521), [6](http://www.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&lang=&Option=FatwaId&Id=22205), [7](http://islamqa.info/ar/ref/103137)

Answer (score -1):

salams i think we can as its good pure energy around the house n as we say we have 5 latifs in our chest do at leadt one of thrm will be listening. olso my soul can listen the wslls n ants n dpiders n jins etc will be listening n birds if windows r open  thsts my brlif as mashallah i leave it on all day n night n it gives sukoon n peace wether i listen or not. forgive sny misunderstanding